# key error while retrieving csv files into list

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

How to prevent error when certain column such as 'Country' does not exist in some file?

```
import csv
files = glob.glob ('..\\*.csv')
for file in files:
    countries = []
    with open ('data.csv', newline='') as infile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
        for row in reader:
            countries.append(row['Country'])
    print (countries)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if field exist

```
if 'Country' in reader.fieldnames:
   ...
```

Or you can deal with a problem at the row level like you'll with any dictionary like structure. You can use `.get` method which will return None if key does not exist:

```
countries.append(row.get('Country'))
```

Alternatively you can use `setdefault` method and provide default value (it can be also done with get):

```
row.setdefault('Country', 'Unknown')
```

or even wrap your code in a try-catch block:

```
try:
    countries.append(row['Country'])
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Combining this with list comprehensions:

```
if 'Country' in reader.fieldnames:
    countries = [row.get('Country') for row in reader]
```

Comment: Typo at `expect`, it should be `except`.